# How do I make a script public in JSFiddle?

Tags: jsfiddle

If I have private scripts, in All your fiddles category how can I move these to Public fiddles category?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

To make a JSFiddle script public:

1. Open the script.
2. Open the Info tab on the left.
3. Enter in a title for the script
4. Press Update.

In this new version of the script, set it as the base version.
Wait several minutes for the script to be visible in your public profile page.

Comment: Just a side note - all fiddles are public. Anyone who knows the URL can access it.

Comment: Yes, anyone who knows the URL can access it

Comment: Thanks for pointing out to set it as base version to get it visible in public profile page.

Comment: They really need to make this more intuitive. I shouldn't have to get on Stack Overflow to figure this out.

Comment: Can you only share things if you are registered in JSFiddle? I cannot see any "Info" tab on the left.