# bootstrap datetimepicker not working

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am trying to put bootstrap datetimepicker plugin in my web app and followed every installation instructions properly but it won't work so I tried the examples of others in jsfiddle referenced from here but they too not work. Is is in my browser or I just forgot to include some requirements. Here is my header:

```
<!-- BOOTSTRAP TIMEPICKER -->
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');?>"
```

and here is my footer:

```
<!-- JQUERY TIMEPICKER -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/moment/min/moment.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');?>"></script>
```

and here is the html:

```
               <tr>
            <td><label class='control-label'>Time In:</label></td>
             <td><div class='input-group date' id='TimeIn'>
             <input type='text' class='form-control' value='".@date('H:i',@strtotime($val['TimeIn']))."' id='txtTimeIn'/><span class='input-group-addon'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></i></span>
             </div></td>
              </tr>
```

And here is the jquery:

```
$(function(){
$('#TimeIn').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
});
});
```

Comment: Check browser console error logs. On Google Chrome `F12 --> Console`.

Comment: The problem is that it never shows any error even jquery conflicts.....

Answer (score 0):

Show the `datetimepicker` after initializing

```
$(function(){
$('#TimeIn').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
});
$("#Timein").datetimepicker("show");
});
```

Comment: I tried but still not working. I tried also this timepicker http://jdewit.github.io/bootstrap-timepicker/ but same thing not working. Please note that I have a calendar plugin. Is ymy calendar can also affect the functionality of other plugins?

Comment: Why you use separate plugins. Use the `datetimepicker` alone where you can use both calendar and time and only a calendar if needed.

Comment: I will try to disable the calendar see if it will work.

Comment: Can you please make the fiddle and share

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23512319/how-do-i-make-a-script-public-in-jsfiddle

Comment: Is it working after changed that? Working means happy : )

Comment: due to my frustration I just used the built in time type input of bootstrap but no animation or flashy what so over just like an ordinary text input with time validation only.... :(

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use it before but i searched and i found some exmaples.
You used `<i>` inside `<span>` but you didn't add icon's attributes

```
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar">
```

check this link https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I am using the glyphicon and that 's how also written in the tutorial.